# How to find the address of a WD EX2 drive?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, dhcp

I have a hard-drive of WD MyCloud EX2 connected to my wifi. I know its address should be something like 10.0.0.X. But I do not know what is X. How do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your WiFi router management menu. You should see list of DHCP assigned IPs somewhere. If you're at home, the list won't be long.

If you're at work, then you can either ask your admin, who has access to the wifi management or DHCP server (if it's special server).

Or you can switch it off, scan your segment for live IPs with

```
nmap -sn 10.0.0.0/24
```

save result. Then switch it on, wait a while to get the IP, do the scan again and compare results.

It may also show you the manufacturer of the device based on MAC. So if you have just one (or a few) WD devices online, you can find it directly. There is example with Raspberry device:

```
Nmap scan report for raspi (192.168.200.108)
Host is up (0.00042s latency).
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:2E:A3:4B (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
```

That should work on Linux, I'm not familiar with Windows world much so I can't provide you exact way

Comment: I am not at home - I am at work, and I do not see the router (I am using the workplace's wifi network). how can I find the WiFi router management menu?

Comment: This worked great! I disconnected the drive cable from the network and did nmap -sn 10.0.0.0/24 > nmap1.txt. Then I reconnected it and did nmap -sn 10.0.0.0/24 > nmap2.txt.  Then I did diff nmap1.txt nmap2.txt | grep -v latency and immediately spotted the IP address.